# Number of solutions of a linear 3x4 equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If I have an inhomogeneous linear equation system with four variables and three equations, how do I see that there are either no solutions or infinitely many? I thought like this: The solution set of the corresponding homogeneous system is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with dimension $0$ or $1$, that is the zero subset and a line through the origin. Then the solution set of the inhomogeneous system will be a translation of this solution set, hence the empty set or a line not through origin.

Comment: Apply the Rouché-Capelli theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

Comment: Well, your argument is wrong. Think about it: the case where $0$ is the only solution of the homogeneous system (i.e. dimension $0$) would correspond, via translation, to the case where the system has exactly **one** solution. Fortunately, here the solution set of the homogeneous system can never be $\{0\}$. The dimension of the solution set of the homogeneous associated system has *never* anything to do with the inhomogeneous system having solutions or not.